# Envio de arquivo para servidor via FTP via linha de comando linux

Tags: linux, ftp

Bom dia. Tenho algumas duvidas referente a um projeto que estou finalizando utilizando linux ( não tenho muito domínio ).

tenho um programa escrito em C que gera arquivos .txt, devo fazer esse programa ser executado todo dia ( até então, sei que devo utilizar a funcionalidade crontab ). 
Após esse arquivo ser gerado devo enviar para um servidor via FTP. 
Neste ponto não sei como prosseguir, tendo em vista que devo acessar o diretório que o arquivo foi gerado, abrir conexão com o FTP e realizar o envio do mesmo.

Outra duvida que estou tendo é, qual a vantagem de utilização de um envio para um servidor através do protocolo FTP?

Edit 1:

Realizei o script e até então funciona quando passo na variavel arquivo o arquivo-origem e origem-arquivo, entretanto é necessário declarar um novo nome, sendo que eu gostaria apenas de duplicar os arquivos de um lugar a outro.

Segue script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='192.168.8.151'
usuario='ftp_tentativas'
senha='passwdwillian01'
arquivo='/var/www/html/log/Export/*.csv'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user ${usuario} ${senha}

cd recebe
put $arquivo
cp /var/www/html/log/Export/*.* /var/www/html/log/Enviados/.
rm /var/www/html/log/Export/*.* 

quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

Erro que apresenta:

```
?Invalid command
Could not create file.
Remove directory operation failed.
```

Quando feito 'a mão' diretamente pelo console ele mostra o destino igual a origem, não criando o arquivo corretamente.

```
ftp> put /var/www/html/log/Export/*.csv
local: /var/www/html/log/Export/Relatorio_Qualidade_20180730.csv remote: /var/www/html/log/Export/Relatorio_Qualidade_20180730.csv
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,8,111,109,45).
553 Could not create file.
```

Comment: Acho que você esta fazendo confusão caro William, o servidor é servidor, o servidor "não é FTP", o FTP é uma ferramenta instalada no servidor (e com porta liberada) para facilitar compartilhar os dados entre sua maquina local e outra maquina, assim como SSH, ou até googledrive, mas funciona em um protocolo proprio (protocolo FTP), teu servidor poderia não ter a ferramenta de FTP que ainda funcionaria igualmente, mas vc teria que usar outros métodos para enviar os arquivos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado pelo retorno, mas acho que não soube me expressar direito, a ideia era explicar que quero enviar o arquvio para o servidor pela protocolo FTP como vc mesmo disse. Mas agradeço o retorno e a especificação. abriu um pouco mais a minha mente haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

primeiro verifique se você tem o cliente FTP instalado na maquina que vai executar cron: 
    apt-get install ftp -y
    # caso seja distribuição seja baseada debian

você pode criar scrip será executado pelo cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='192.168.8.151'
usuario='ftp_tentativas'
senha='passwdwillian01'

arquivo='*.csv'

cd /var/www/html/log/Export/

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user ${usuario} ${senha}
prompt
mput $arquivo
quit
END_SCRIPT
cp /var/www/html/log/Export/*.* /var/www/html/log/Enviados/.
rm /var/www/html/log/Export/*.* 
exit 0
```

Geralmente protocolo FTP não é muito utilizado por não ter criptografia, geralmente é utilizado SFTP,  FTPS.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson. só por uma duvida. quando eu chamo o campo /caminho/do/arquivo é para o arquivo que esta sendo gerado correto? Onde eu definiria para onde este arquivo deve ser enviado?

Comment: Ah beleza, entendido!

Comment: Opa blz, só mais uma duvida que me surgiu, eu consigo criar esse script direto no cron?

Comment: Opa, entendido. Obrigado!

Comment: estou com mais uma duvida... no script que fiz em C estou querendo realizar o seguinte procedimento enviar o arquivo com o nome em que ele é gerado na pasta, após isso copiar esse arquivo para uma outra pasta e remover os dados do atual. o script esta na pergunta ( editada ) mas ele me retorna alguns erros ( seguem na pergunta editada tambem) para realizar via put  a sintaxe difere de um bash ''comum?''